# Is it possible to sort the post based on a custom field?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, post-meta

I have a custom field called "value_date" where add a date 
e.g yyyy/mm/dd

The idea is sort the upcoming dates first in the loop, is possible?

I used a template for custom post taxonomy-event-date.php and this is code in the function, It doesn't work.

**Functions.php**

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
function search_filter($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->
is_tax( 'event', 'date' ) ) {
        $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
        $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
        $query->set('meta_value', $today);
        $query->set('meta_key', 'value_date');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible, look around for `pre_get_posts` questions, however- your date format is incorrect and will need to be changed to yyyy/mm/dd to sort correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
You can call action "pre_get_posts".

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

You can add parameter :

```
$args = array(
  'post_status'       => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'    => 6,
  'paged'             => $paged,
  'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
  'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

You can use above parameter e.g. :

```
function search_filter($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be done in the same default main query of the template taxonomy-event-date.php ?

Comment: It will work by default on taxonomy-event-date.php but you need to validate for specific page taxonomy-event-date in search filter. Otherwise it will load for all pages.

Comment: Thanks Punit!, With the above query does not work because the page appear 404 error when going to the second page

Comment: Hi @Max You need to add `$query->set('paged', $page)` in search_filter function here you will get $page value by `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`

Comment: Hi @punit-patel It doesn't work, check my edit

Comment: @Max you are querying for posts with dates that match `$today`. You don't want to set `meta_value` unless you are looking for a specific value. Note that the code in the answer above does not set `meta_value`.